# Get twitter hashtags by country

Tags: php, javascript, twitter, oauth

Would it be possible (either in Javascript/AJAX or PHP) to get some twitter data (preferably some hardcoded hashtags), but based on countries? Does Twitter give you this kind of information?

Basically, I want something like: "How many users used the tag `#sex` grouped by country and show only top 10 countries"

One solution would be to get all tweets with `#<country>` and then see how many also contain `#sex`, but that would mean to get a **huge** amount of tweets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the Twitter search API documented here:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search

To do something similar to what you are asking, I use the geocode attribute, which allows you to return tweets within a certain radius of a long/lat point. My example below returns tweets within 350miles of the centre of England.

http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=search&callback=?&rpp=25&geocode=54.16243396806781,-3.6474609375,350mi

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: This works for me... it's a bit slow on their end, but it's mainly what I've been looking for. Thanks!